# Validating user swift 4, login page

Tags: ios, swift

I need to my button `proceedToAppFeatures` to run the code and display an alert of success or failure login(just a single user, for now)

I have tried `self.showAlert` and `self.present`

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import FLAnimatedImage
import ImageIO
import UserNotifications//import this to use user notifications
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var background: FLAnimatedImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblValidationTxt: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblValidationMessage: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        background.loadGif(name: "neon lights")

        passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true// the password will no be visible
        emailTextField.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self

        let Tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DismissKeyboard))//here i have used the function to didmiss the keyboard

            view.addGestureRecognizer(Tap)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        //this initialize the permission that will appear on user screen
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted,error) in
            //enable or disable features based on the authorization
        }

//        emailTextField.text = ""
//        passwordTextField.text = ""//on view did load to store text field property

        }

    @objc func DismissKeyboard() {//function that implements the type outside the screen
        view.endEditing(true)

    }
    @IBAction func sigInButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "userData", sender: true)

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == emailTextField {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }else{
            passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()//just to decide which of the buttons will respond after a tab is pressed
            passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }

    func showAlert(title: String, message: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: {(action) in alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    }

    @IBAction func proceedToAppFeatures(_ sender: Any) {
        let email = isValidEmail(testStr: emailTextField.text!)

        if email == false{
            self.showAlert(title: "ERROR", message: "This is not a valid e-mail. Please try again")
            emailTextField.text = ""
        }else{
            self.showAlert(title: "Success", message: "Yousucessifully loged in")
            //performSegue(withIdentifier: "formPage", sender: true)
        }

        let myEmail: String!
        myEmail = emailTextField.text!

        let myPassword: String!
        myPassword = passwordTextField.text!

        if(myEmail == "leandroaaramos" && myPassword == "123456"){
           //performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSegue", sender: nil)
            //code for the truth
            print("You are success")
        }else if (myEmail.isEmpty && myPassword.isEmpty){
            //here i put the alert message
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wow", message: "Hold on fill the gaps", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            //add an action to the alert
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.showAlert(title: "Empty field", message: "Try again")

        }else {
            //here i put the alert message
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ops", message: "Your account is not here", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            //add an action to the alert
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.showAlert(title: "Sorry", message: "Can't find you.")

        }


    }

}
```

I want go to my `loginViewController`, if the user leandroaaramos and password 123456 was typed.

Comment: It doesn't show the alert? What happens when you click the button? Any error? If not, try to put a print inside the button method like `print("tapped")`to know if it's executing the action

Comment: xcode show me the following error :Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f806a821c00> on <PartyFinder2.ViewController: 0x7f8068c0b4f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: i have already a print inside, but it shows me nothing of my print statement

Comment: hmm that's weird. I don't see any print in your `IBAction`, however, usually you get that error when views are not loaded yet (i.e. in viewDidLoad), but shouldn't happen when you tap a button...

Comment: sorry mate, i figured that out, you help me a lot with that print advise, turns out i was putting the proceed segue at the wrong place, before the loop of those alerts alerts that i wanted to show. thanks

Comment: I'm glad you got it!